# Error from SP.Runtime.JS - The collection has not been initialized

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm creating a page layout in SharePoint 2010 that dynamically calls in a list in order to generate a navbar as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getNavbar, "sp.js"); 
});

function getNavbar(){
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("/abc/");

    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Topics");  
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Order0' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy></Query></View>");
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuery), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}

function onQuery(sender, args) { ...  }
function onQueryFailed(sender, args){ ... }
```

Sometimes I get an error from `sp.runtime.js`

> The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed...

And there are times when there are no errors. I replaced

`ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getNavbar, "sp.js");`

with

`SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getNavbar);`

and then with

`_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("getNavbar");`

Nothing seems to work. I finally tried `setTimerout()` and it works; however, I know this method is not reliable for other computers. Is there another method I can use to fix this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my question. In order to avoid all the javascript errors, I created a customized master page that would be used throughout the site. The masterpage had all the jquery/javascript references. Then I used `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function, "sp.js")` in the page layouts and/or individual pages to call the functions.